# What version of windows can be virtualized?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, license

I have an Ubuntu machine that I want to have windows virtualized in with VirtualBox.  Is there a specific version of Windows 7 that I have to have so that the license will allow me to virtualize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any commercial license for any version of Windows 7(or any version of Windows) will work just fine.

Comment: And I believe you can use any version (win7) for 30 days even without a licence.

Comment: I thought that there was more to it, something about an enterprise license or something.

Comment: Badges... we don't need no stinking badges.

Comment: You can even rearm windows after the 30 days have expired to get a trial period of up to 120 days.

Comment: From http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/faq.asp "Q: What are the virtualization rights for Windows 7? (That is, which versions are licensed for install in virtual machines by consumers?)

A: Windows 7 Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate can be installed in virtual environments."